# How to resolve casting Error in DB2 Boolean to .NET Core Boolean?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, db2, entity-framework-core

I need to cast Booleans from a DB2 Query to Booleans in .NET Core

I've got a query to check wheter a string matches with a Regex.

I tried multiple casts: BOOLEAN, TINYINT, SMALLINT.

`CASE WHEN (REGEXP_LIKE(TESTNAME.COL1, 'Test1')) THEN CAST(true AS BOOLEAN) ELSE CAST(false AS SMALLINT) END as Error`

My Entity looks something like that:

```
public class ErrorView {
    [Required] public string Key { get; set; }
    public bool Error { get; set; }
}
```

A connection to the database can be established, this is not the problem.

However, I get the following

> Error: System.InvalidCastException - Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Int16' to type 'System.Boolean'

.

The exact same code works perfectly combined with a MySQL Server (given some adaptations in the SQL-Query). The Query itself works in Datagrip.

Edit 1:
I'm using the NuGet Package IBM.EntityFrameworkCore in Version 1.3.0.100.
And for developing I use a Windows 10 (64 Bit) on a x64-Processor.

Edit 2:
This is what I call:

```
ExternalDbContextFactory dbContextFactory = new  ExternalDbContextFactory(applicationDbContextOptions);
var context = dbContextFactory.Create();
var sqlRuleResult = context.EntityName.FromSql(regexRule);
```

I get the casting error in a Microsoft-Method. Trying to cast it manually in the Entity does not work since it does not reach that point.

Stacktrace:

> at  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource.TryReadValue[TValue](ValueBuffer& valueBuffer, Int32 index, IPropertyBase property)
>
> at lambda_method(Closure , MaterializationContext )
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.UnbufferedEntityShaper`1.Shape(QueryContext queryContext, ValueBuffer& valueBuffer)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()

Comment: Please check below link if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389561/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-boolean-values-in-db2

Comment: Thank you, but the Problem there is a wrong DB2 Version. I am able to cast to Boolean on DB2 - through Datagrip or directly in the webview (I'm using IBMs Lite Version for Development). It only doesn't work in my .NET Core application

Comment: I created a new DB2 Lite Version on the IBM Cloud about two weeks ago. So I guess its the newest version, but can't find a concrete number.

Comment: Ah I am using the NuGet-Packages from IBM:
IBM.EntityFrameworkCore in Version 1.3.0.100 and I'm running a 64 Bit Version of Windows on a x64-based processor.

Comment: Possible that DB2Type Boolean may cause runtime exception if used in .net, as IBM.Data.DB2Types Namespace may not yet natively support Db2Type boolean.  Consider using only SMALLINT in the query.

Comment: As written in the question, I've also already tried with SMALLINT. It does not work (System.Int16 to System.Boolean Cast error). I will update my question with the Nuget information - thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Until native support for Db2type Boolean to System.Boolean is available in the provider, can't you manually map (from smallint to System.Boolean) via explicit code in your class?  Not elegant, but if needs must...   I don't know if there are alternative methods at present.

Comment: @mao I tried to manually cast in the Entity - it didn't work. I updated with a more specific Stacktrace. I wonder what I can do anymore since it's located inside a Microsoft Library. 
The general call-structure should be okay since it works flawlessly with MySQL Servers and a corresponding MySQL-RegexRule

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply not using a boolean but an integer. It's not ideal since it requires different handling later on in the code, but it works that way.

```
public class ErrorView {
    [Required] public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Error { get; set; }
}
```